# jQuery function not working if anchored link clicked in different page

Tags: html, jquery

My simple jQuery function works fine if I click an anchored link on page-1 (body turns black fine) BUT if I have the same anchored link on another page-2 to link back and anchor to my page-1 the function doesn't work? It goes back to page-1 fine but body on page-1 doesn't turn black as expected?

HTML on page-1:

```
<div id="offcanvas">
  <a href="#key-features" class="nav-link">
  <span>Key features</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

HTML on page-2:

```
<div id="offcanvas">
  <a href="page-1.htm#key-features" class="nav-link">
  <span>Key features</span>
</a>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#offcanvas a").click(function(){
    $('.offcanvas').offcanvas('hide');
    $("body").css('background-color', '#000000')
});
```

Many thanks in advance for your help.
B]

Comment: What's defining your page-1/page-2?  Is it a [tag:datatables]?   Events only apply to elements that exist when the code runs - if you use datatables (or similar) to "page" your data then those elements will be created after your event handler code has run, so the handler won't apply to them.  Try changing to `$(document).on("click", "#offcanvas a", function() ...` to use event delegation.

Comment: Thank you @freedomn-m. No datatables. Your solution works IF you are on page-1 (click the link and body becomes black) BUT if you are on page-2 and click the link TO GO BACK to page-1 the body of page-1 should be black but it isn't.... Any other ideas? thank you

Comment: What's defining your page-1/page-2?

Comment: If you want the page to restore any changes made when you go *back* - then you need to tell the browser to store those changes.  When you *back*, the page will revert to its initial load state, along with any forms filled.  Any changes made by js will not be restored/reapplied.   Lookup `history.pushState` to store the current state after it changes (not before you navigate away)

Comment: If you want the page to restore any changes made when you next open that page (ie go *forward*) then look at `localStorage` to store the current state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I manage to find the solution, this works:

```
$("#offcanvas a").on("click", function() {
    if (window.location.hash) {
      $("body").css('background-color', 'black');
}
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

please use below html structure
you have not define id on html structure

```
<div id="offcanvas">
  <a href="#key-features" class="nav-link">
    <span>Key features</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Patel but even with that id added it still doesn't work...